# Entity Framework with Repository Pattern insert many-to-many

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I have inherited a solution that's using Entity Framework with Repository Pattern.
In this solution the previous developers have forgotten to implement a many-to-many relationship, so now I have to do it instead.

I'm not too familiar with either EF or the pattern so I just can't get what I'm trying to accomplish to actually work, which is to insert into a many-to-many relationship.
I can get EF to create the relationship table in the database, but somehow I can't insert into it.

I have seen [other questions similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576916/ef-repository-pattern-many-to-many-insert), but none of them match exactly how the pattern is implemented here, and then me being unfamiliar with everything can't wrap my head around it.

Can someone please take a look at the code and see what I'm missing? (Code has been simplified a bit and this is no actual Student/Course project, but I'm using those names as they have been used in previous examples)

Here's my code. Very simplified and without thousands of interfaces.
This runs just fine with no exceptions.
When I debug and quickwatch the `studentUow` in the "Main" class, the Students.Courses collection does indeed contain a value, but it is never saved to the database. Also, it contains only one value, even though it should contain several courses.

### Entity classes

```
public class Student { // This class already existed
    public int StudentId { get; protected set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; } // I added this property
}

public class Course { // This class already existed
    public int CourseId { get; protected set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; } // I added this property
}
```

### Repository

```
public class StudentRepository {
    protected DbContext DbContext { get; private set; }
    protected DbSet<Student> DbSet { get; private set; }
    public StudentRepository(DbContext dbContext) {
        DbContext = dbContext;
        DbSet = dbContext.Set<Student>();
    }

    public virtual void AddOrUpdate(Student entity) {
        if (Exists(entity)) {
            Update(entity);
        } else {
            Add(entity);
        }
    }

    public virtual void Update(Student entity) {
        var dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State == EntityState.Detached) {
            DbSet.Attach(entity);
        }
        dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public virtual Student Add(Student entity) {
        var dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Detached) {
            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Added;
        } else {
            return DbSet.Add(entity);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public IQueryable<Student> Queryable() {
        return DbSet;
    }

    public bool Exists(Student entity) {
        var objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext).ObjectContext;
        object existingEntity;
        var exists = objContext.TryGetObjectByKey(GetEntityKey(entity), out existingEntity);
        if (exists) objContext.Detach(existingEntity);

        return exists;
    }

    private EntityKey GetEntityKey(Student entity) {
        var objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext).ObjectContext;
        var objSet = objContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
        var entityKey = objContext.CreateEntityKey(objSet.EntitySet.Name, entity);
        return entityKey;
    }
}
```

### Unit of work

```
public class StudentUow : UnitOfWork<MyDbContext> {
    public StudentRepository Students { get { return CreateRepository<StudentRepository>(); } }
    public CourseRepository Courses { get { return CreateRepository<CourseRepository>(); } }
}

public class UnitOfWork<TContext> where TContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext {
    private readonly TContext _dbContext;
    private IRepositoryProvider _repositoryProvider;

    protected UnitOfWork(IRepositoryProvider provider) {
        _repositoryProvider = provider;
    }

    protected TRepository CreateRepository<TRepository>() {
        return _repositoryProvider.Create<TRepository>(_dbContext, "default");
    }

    public void Commit() {
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}

[Export(typeof(IUnitOfWorkProvider))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class UnitOfWorkProvider {
    [Import] private IRepositoryProvider _repositoryProvider;

    public StudentUow GetStudentUow() {
        return new StudentUow(_repositoryProvider);
    }
}

[Export(typeof(IRepositoryProvider))]
public class MyRepositoryProvider {
    public MyRepositoryProvider() {
        Register<RepositoryFactory<IProductRepository, StudentRepository>>();
    }

    public TRepository Create<TRepository>(DbContext dbContext, string conntextKey)
    {
        var type = typeof (TRepository);
        if (!_factories.ContainsKey(type))
            throw new UnknownFactoryException(type);

        return (TRepository)_factories[type].Create(dbContext);
    }

    public void Register<TRepositoryFactory>() where TRepositoryFactory : IRepositoryFactory, new()
    {
        var factory = new TRepositoryFactory();
        if (_factories.ContainsKey(factory.Type)) throw new FactoryTypeAlreadyRegisteredException(factory.Type);
        _factories[factory.Type] = factory;
    }
}
```

### "Main" class

```
public class MyClass {
    public AddCourse(int studentId, List<int> courses) {
        using (var studentUow = new StudentUow()) {
            foreach (int courseId in courses) {
                Student s = studentUow.Student.Queryable().First(x => x.StudentId == studentId);
                Course c = studentUow.Course.Queryable().First(x => x.CourseId == courseId);
                s.Courses.Add(c);

                studentUow.Student.AddOrUpdate(s);
            }
            studentUow.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

*If you're missing some functionality, leave a comment and I'll add it, or let you know where it is.*

Comment: please http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: The actual project is filled with tons of UOWs, Repositories, Interfaces, and uses some MEF to instantiate up various stuff. I wouldn't even know where to start to create a SSCCE of that mess.

Comment: Can you post the code for CreateRepository<T>? My initial thought is each repository is creating a new DbContext so there is no relationship between the two. Therefore when you use the Queryable methods on these two, they are still proxy objects so creating the many-to-many wont work. Make sure the DbContext references the same object, or try ToList on both Queryables so they aren't proxy objects.

Comment: @ManOVision Code updated. As you can see some of this stuff is instantiated by MEF.

Comment: What is the lifecycle of MyDbContext. Is a new one instantiated every time, or is it a singleton? Either way could bring problems in different areas of the code. I suggest breaking out of the repository pattern and have your "Main" class interact with directly with MyDbContext. This way you can remove doubts of the issue being on EF or somewhere else. If your many-to-many objects are added just fine, you may have a lot of code to dig through. If they aren't added, it may be simple MyDbContext code changes or database changes.

Comment: @ManOVision MyDbContext is instantiated by MEF. It also has a static constructor, so it should be a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

EF is not including related entities in queries by default. In order to to this, you need to include Courses manually when needed. Also there is a problem that on each iteration you are fetching student again and again so the collection of courses is lost. This should work:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
...
using (var studentUow = new StudentUow()) {
    Student s = studentUow.Student.Queryable().Include(x => x.Courses).First(x => x.StudentId == studentId);
    foreach (int courseId in courses) {
        Course c = studentUow.Course.Queryable().First(x => x.CourseId == courseId);
        s.Courses.Add(c);
        c.Students.Add(s);

        studentUow.Course.Update(c);
    }
    studentUow.Student.Update(s);
    studentUow.Commit();
}
```

I would highly recommend refactoring your code if possible.

Comment: I tried this, but still nothing was inserted into the relation-table. Maybe refactoring everything is the way to go. Any tips on a good pattern to use that is preferrably modular?

Comment: First, try using DbContext directly to see if it works. Then I would pass DbContext instance to repositories via DI. UoW would also have DbContext instance so Commit calls DbContext.SaveChanges(). Also you need to specify lifetime of DbContext to be per request in your IoC container.